# dispatch is not a function TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm new to react-redux and I'm using the react-thunk middleware. I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function" whenever I try to run my action creator (by pressing my button). Anyone know what's going on?

**src/actions/index.js**

```
function editUserName (newUserName) {
    return {
        type: 'CHANGE_USER_NAME',
        newUserName: newUserName
    }
}

export function editUserNameDelegate () {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        return dispatch(editUserName("thunkUser"))
    }
}
```

**src/containers/admin.js**

```
import { editUserNameDelegate } from '../actions/index'
...
<input type="button" onClick={ editUserNameDelegate() } value="edit UserName" />
```

Comment: return function (dispatch, getState) {
        return dispatch(editUserName("thunkUser"))
    } in this function you have taken dispatch as argument and in the second line treating as function???

Answer (score 6):

You're executing the `editUserNameDelegate` function inside of `render`, instead of passing it as the `onClick` handler.  You want `onClick={editUserNameDelegate}` instead.

Also, if you're writing it that way, you need to make sure that the function is bound up to dispatch when you call it.  You can do that like:

`export default connect(null, {editUserNameDelegate})(MyComponent)`

And then pass `onClick={this.props.editUserNameDelegate}` in your render function.

Answer (score 0):

The store is what provides the `dispatch` function. So you either need to connect your component to the store using something like `connect` from react-redux (https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux), or you need to call `store.dispatch(editUserNameDelegate())`.

You also need to make sure you have added redux-thunk as middleware in your store. See more about redux-thunk here: https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Answer (score 0):

You should provide what is src/containers/admin.js function or class?

If it is function component you should use `onClick={() => editUserNameDelegate()}`

Answer (score 0):

If This Error Is As A Result Of Using context you might consider importing it as:
const {state, dispatch} = useContext(location of the context)